# Good service for getting location by IP?

Tags: php, asp.net, geolocation, location, ip

Which detect location most accurate.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.maxmind.com/ 's free API will get you to country level, and city for some IPs, if you pay them you can get some more detail, this information is a good default, but not 100% accurate. It's the best I've found.

Comment: They have a free "GeoLite City" database as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely free web service

http://www.hostip.info/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/) before and it works great.  The free version will only return the country but the pay versions are very accurate and will return alot more information. They have API's for a lot of common languages.

Comment: They are the absolute worst people to deal with. There are no free plans, not even for country. Once you pay, they make you answer 7 questions via email, and then they give you a crappy product that you need to update yourself. What is wrong with you back-end folks? Can't resist doing a tonne of work for one tiny bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

The [Geo IP](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip) PECL package and [Net_GeoIP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP) PEAR package both provide an interface to the maxmind location database (that been mentioned in other answers) for PHP.